# Why is magic so exhausting?

Tags: adom

I just rolled my second Wizard character, and I'm going around blithely killing enemies with my Magic Missiles. However, I'm seeing a message I never saw with my first character who used this spell.

> Do you want to exhaust yourself casting this spell? [y/N]

If I choose yes, I receive another message.

> Part of your life energy is drained while casting the spell!

My HP decreases in order to cast the spell. What is causing this? Is my Concentration too low to cast spells in quick succession like on my last wizard?

Comment: I know the question is old, but I just found a useful, possibly game breaking trick that abuses this feature of the game. If you have the Cure Critical Wounds spell, and cast it while having no MP, you will lose a bit of HP in order to cast it, but you will regain a lot more than you spent. In this way, you can heal yourself completely without using any MP. You can even use your newly gained HP to pay for more spells, then use CCW again to recover, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have enough power points to cast the spell your health is drained instead. Spend a few turns walking around or waiting until your power points regenerate.

Comment: Alternatively, grab healing spells.  Healing spells heal more than they expend in health, allowing theoretical unlimited casting.  Concentration's the better way to go about it, though.